# NextJs CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, cors, next.js

I have a Next.js app hosted on Vercel at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), which needs to communicate with a backend .NET Core Web API hosted on a different server at api.example.com.
The .NET core web api has been configured to allow CORS but my Next.js keeps complaining that data cannot be displayed when I use AXIOS to fetch data because the response lacks allow-cors headers:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com' from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

It works fine when I run it locally using `npm run dev`, but doesn't work when I build it and then run `npm run start`

Does anyone know how to fix the cors issue in production?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say that the server is “configured to allow CORS”? Seems like your backend isn’t allow-listing your frontend.

Comment: @JBallin The .NET Core Web API uses .UseCors middleware to allow CORS access. The back-end appears to be working fine because I also have a React App created using create-react-app and served as static file. That app is able to communicate with my backend just fine. I assume the problem here has something to do with the Next.Js server side logic

Comment: The crazy thing on my side is it does authentication but fails to fetch other data

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites):

Basically, I just need to add a next.config.js file in the root directory and add the following:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'https://api.example.com/:path*',
          },
        ]
      },
  };
```

Comment: I got the answer and it works. But why exactly is this happening on NextJS?

Comment: It does not work on Vercel. Any clue why?

Comment: I thnk what happens here is that this config will be passed to the next.js server to proxy all calls to example.com/api to api.example.com. It should work on Vercel as I deployed my app there and it seems to work fine.

Comment: You'll need to add the same config to vercel.json too: https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors#enabling-cors-using-vercel.json

Comment: I cannot make use of that solution because in POST requests body is not send, can anybody help?

Answer (score 24):

if you want to use the `cors` library in `nextjs`, I created a library for it is [`nextjs-cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/nextjs-cors).

https://www.npmjs.com/nextjs-cors

https://github.com/yonycalsin/nextjs-cors

> pages/api/whoami.{ts,js}

```
import NextCors from 'nextjs-cors';

async function handler(req, res) {
   // Run the cors middleware
   // nextjs-cors uses the cors package, so we invite you to check the documentation https://github.com/expressjs/cors
   await NextCors(req, res, {
      // Options
      methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
      origin: '*',
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
   });

   // Rest of the API logic
   res.json({ message: 'Hello NextJs Cors!' });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue, I was making the call from this page:

**pages/page1.js**

```
  export default async function page1() {
       const data = await axios.post('https://www.dominio.com/xxx' , {param: 1}, headers)
}
```

But the solution is to make axios calls to a local API file inside "pages/api" directory, and this local API file, will handle the request to the external webserver. This avoid the CORS issue.

**pages/page1.js**

```
export default async function page1() {
        const data = await axios.post('/api/get_page1_data', {param: 1} )
}
```

**pages/api/get_page1_data.js**

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
try{
   const data = await axios.post('https://www.dominio.com/xxx' , {param: req.body.param}, headers)
    res.status(200).json(data)
 } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message)
  }
```

Comment: in my case

const resp = await axios.get('https://www.dominio.com/xxx')
res.status(200).json(resp.data)

Comment: This trick working on my end . Thank you so much Bro for saving my time

Comment: that means you are making two requests instead of one. 
one for the next server and the other for API which does not make sense.

Comment: Is this when deployed on vercel?

Comment: Hi @m3.b No, not in Vercel.

Answer (score 15):

it was a problem in the server not accepting OPTIONS requests, because routes were declared as GET::something or POST:: something, so the preflight couldn't pass and the POST request was decliend, hope this will help another people to prevent hours of googling, so in my case (Node.js + Express.js) i had to add this to my server.js

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
  if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Do an extra check if your base URL is correct that was my issue

Comment: I had an extra '/' before my query string that botched it all. :joy: ty!

Answer (score 3):

After many research, I finally find the answer, there are two ways of doing it, if you are not hosted in vercel:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.com',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

export default function handler(req, res) {
  cors(corsOptions)(req, res, () => {
    // Your API code here
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello, World!' });
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/nextjs-cors as mentioned in the previous post, which is similar with this method.

If you are hosting on vercel (refer to doc [here](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors)):

1. In the root directory of your project, create a file named
   vercel.json.
2. Add the following code to the vercel.json file:

```js
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After deploying your project, Vercel will automatically apply the CORS configuration defined in the vercel.json file to your API routes.

Comment: In what file did you place your first snippet of `handler` code?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the preflight request was failing due to an agressive HTTP method filter.

Make sure that you specify

```
  // Preflight Check:
  if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    return res.status(202).json({});
  }

  // Allow only POST Methods 
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    return res.status(405).json({ error: `Method ${req.method} Not Allowed` });
  }
```

You can allow all methods with https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors#enabling-cors-in-a-next.js-app, but make sure that each endpoint returns a 2XX status code for the OPTIONS HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure it is `CORS` and is not something else. For example, in my case I was getting a `400` response. Please look on the `Response` tab of that request for information.

Comment: It clearly stated that they are having next cors issues. 400 status code cant be related to CORs issue especially next with issues with cors

Answer (score 0):

after hours of googleing i found the solution on the next-docs itself!!!

see the following repository on github

**API Routes Example with CORS**

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-cors

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that although I configured CORS in my .NET API, but I didn't register the CORS middleware, which your Next js app was trying to use.

So don't forget to add

```
app.UseCors();
```

when you configure your request pipeline (Configure method in the old startup.cs). This will add the necessary options endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

For my case the problem was I was making a request to http://127.0.0.1:3000 and my next js app was running on localhost:3000 this was raising the CORS issue. I only changed the request to be made to http://localhost:3000. So remember to check the base of your api endpoint otherwise that was my resolve

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the,
I was using Nextjs for FE and NodeJs, Express for BE.
I use [cors][1] npm library to solve this issue in Nodejs

```js
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Use this code in app.js of NodeJS file
[1]: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to change the way of managing data fetching, when the error occurred, I performed the fetching from the client side, when I refactored the code to a fetching from the server side it worked without problems.

## Previously

- Page

```js
// src/pages/home.js
import formServices from "@/services/test.service";

export default function PageHome({
 return (
 <div>
  <button onClick={()=>testService.getPing();}>PING</button>
 </div>
 );
})
```

- Service

```js
// src/services/test.service.js
import axios from "axios";
async function getPing() {
  const response = await axios.get("https://example.com/v2/api/ping");
  return await response.data;
}

const testServices = {
 getPing,
};

export default testServices;
```

### Response

- API Rest logs only returned code 204 at the OPTIONS request for preflight.
- A response with code 307 Temporary Redirect appears in the browser.

## Refactoring

- Page

```js
// src/pages/home.js
import formServices from "@/services/test.service";

export default function PageHome({
 return (
 <div>
  <button onClick={()=>testService.getPing();}>PING</button>
 </div>
 );
})
```

- Service

```js
// src/services/test.service.js
import axios from "axios";
async function getPing() {
  const response = await axios.get("/api/ping"); // get request to API Routes of NextJS
  return await response.data;
}

const testServices = {
 getPing,
};

export default testServices;
```

- API Route

```js
// src/app/api/ping/route.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import axios from "axios";
export async function GET() {
  const response = await axios.get("https://example.com/v2/api/ping").then((res) => {
    return res.data;
  });
  return NextResponse.json(response);
}
```

## Response

- Rest logs API returns code 204 for OPTIONS and 200 for GET request.
- In the browser it looks like code 204 for OPTIONS and 200 for the GET request response.

Answer (score -1):

I have Next.js application that has graphql and Apollo Client setup (apollo version : 3.5.10). In order to make a query inside any component you have to use "client" variable that Apollo Client provide. You need to have apollo-client.js file in your project root so that Apollo Client can use it inside any component for query. Inside any component when you trying to make a query like: client.query(...), with these settings of apollo-client file it will throw "cors" error. However you can fix this by adding headers property inside apollo-client file.

This is OLD Settings:

**apollo-client.js** (old)

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

This is NEW Settings:

**apollo-client.js** (new)

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    fetchOptions: {
      mode: 'no-cors',
    },
  },
});

export default client;
```

By doing this, you won't get any "cors" error while doing query inside any component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue taking a SoloLearn NestJS course and it was resolved by adding the line: **app.enableCors()** in **main.ts** file on the root folder in the NESTJs Project.
The file was like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score -2):

On NEST JS, in your main.ts file

Do this

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  //Use this to remove cors errors from client side request
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
      return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
  });

  await app.listen(4000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score -2):

for anyone using .NET 6 and facing this issue -> I used app.UseCors(e=>e.AllowAnyOrigin()); in Program.cs and i could resolve the issue.