# Rewrites not working on Vercel (in production) NextJS

Tags: url-rewriting, next.js, vercel, dynamic-routing

I have been trying to get Rewrites working in NextJS for my API Paths. It was to avoid CORS issues.

I followed the solution from: [NextJs CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue).

It is working on localhost but does not work in a production environment (I was deploying on Vercel itself).

I basically tried with all the types of rewrites:

```
async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: "/api/:path*",
          destination: `https://example.com/api/v1/:path*`,
          basePath: false,
        },
      ],
      afterFiles: [
        {
          source: "/api/:path*",
          destination: `https://example.com/api/v1/:path*`,
          basePath: false,
        },
      ],
      fallback: [
        {
          source: "/api/:path*",
          destination: `https://example.com/api/v1/:path*`,
          basePath: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

This rewrite works on localhost but on production, the rewrite stops working and the API calls go to `/api/:path*` itself.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. Are you certain it's not hitting the rewrite destination but failing for some other reason? Does the same happen if you use [`rewrites` in `vercel.json`](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#project-configuration/rewrites) instead?

Comment: I added the rewrites on `next.config.js` file. Did not add it in `vercel.json`.

Comment: I realise that - I was suggesting adding it to `vercel.json` to verify the issue can still be replicated.

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/api` path is reserved for their Serverless Functions. Changing the source path to something else would resolve the issue.