# Handling cors with next.js

Tags: javascript, heroku, next.js, cors, netlify

I'm using netlify as my front end and heroku with Next.js as my backend

on the front end I'm sending a fetch request like this:

```
fetch(`https://backendname.herokuapp.com/data`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"category":"_main"})
  }).then(...);
```

and in my `pages/api/data.js` in the backend:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    req.body=JSON.parse(req.body);

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://frontendname.netlify.app/");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
    )
    if(req.method!='POST')
     return res.end();

    res.json({...})

}
```

I even added [this](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors#enabling-cors-in-a-next.js-app) to my next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "https://frontendname.netlify.app/" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

but I get this error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://backendname.herokuapp.com/data' from
> origin 'https://frontendname.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I'm trying not to use any third party packages like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem(s)

`https://frontendname.netlify.app/` is *not* an [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin). Because the CORS middleware observes a mismatch between

- the actual origin of your request (`https://frontendname.netlify.app`), and
- the "origin" that you've allowed in your CORS configuration (`https://frontendname.netlify.app/`),

it doesn't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, which causes the preflight check to fail.

You also seem to set CORS headers in multiple places, which isn't a good idea.

### Solution

Drop that trailing slash in the value set in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and don't specify duplicate CORS headers in the response.

Comment: @cakelover Have you removed the trailing slash in `next.config.js`?