# Make API call to IPFS URI with `fetch` in javascript / typescript (Blocked by cors, network error, or type error)

Tags: javascript, typescript, cors, fetch, ipfs

I have a nextjs typescript project running in the browser that needs to make the following `fetch` request:

```js
        const tokenURIResponse = await fetch(
            "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json"
        )
```

This call returns a JSON object that looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "PUG",
  "description": "An adorable PUG pup!",
  "image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmSsYRx3LpDAb1GZQm7zZ1AuHZjfbPkD6J7s9r41xu1mf8?filename=pug.png",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "cuteness",
      "value": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I keep getting the following errors:

Brave:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Source
components/NFTBox.tsx (85:39) @ _callee$

  83 | 
  84 |         // const tokenURIResponse = await fetch(tokenURI as string)
> 85 |         const tokenURIResponse = await fetch(
     |                                       ^
  86 |             "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json",
  87 |         )
```

Firefox:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Source

components/NFTBox.tsx (85:39) @ _callee$

  84 | 
> 85 |         const tokenURIResponse = await fetch(
     |                                       ^
  86 |             "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json",
  87 |         )
```

And when I look at the request in my debug tools, I see this:

```
Request URL: ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: XXXXXX
```

How do I fix this? I've seen questions [talking about CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue) and [articles explaining cors](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9) but I'm not sure I follow what the suggestions are.

What do I need to do to make an API call to an IPFS node in my project?

EDIT: For those trying to test, you might need the [IPFS Companion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipfs-companion/nibjojkomfdiaoajekhjakgkdhaomnch?hl=en)

Comment: Where is this code running? In the browser or Node?

Comment: Browser, I'll update

Comment: Mine says _'URL scheme "ipfs" is not supported'_. Chrome 99.0.4844.51

Comment: Just updated to include the IPFS Companion

Comment: I'm not familiar with IPFS Companion, but I think it works as a proxy to capture the requests and forward to a relevant gateway URL (since `ipfs://` scheme isn't supported yet). What protocol, host, and port is the companion listening on?

Comment: Everyone can add their own custom setup for the companion 

Comment: @PatrickCollins did you have IPFS local node running?

Comment: I do, I think we have to assume the port of every node on the client side, or just use a gateway like the other comments have suggested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phil's comment is in the right direction: Few browsers support the "ipfs://" scheme natively.

Currently the browsers which support it out of the box are Brave and Opera, each handles it a bit differently however - so test your code.

The safe cross-browser approach at this point is to extract the CID and create a new URL to address that CID through an IPFS HTTP gateway, and fetch() that URL instead.

You can find a list of IPFS HTTP gateways here:

https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/

Comment: Yeah that's the work around I'm going with at the moment, just using a gateway. It doesn't feel amazing, but I think it's the "easiest" to do right now.

Comment: Using a public gateway completely defeats the purpose of using IPFS in the first place and IMO isn't a reasonable solution to this problem.  The idea here would be to do something like first try `ipfs://...` and then if that doesn't work *fallback* to a gateway, but currently it seems that `ipfs://...` will *always* fail, even if the browser supports `ipfs` scheme via extension.