# Firebase: Cross-origin redirection to (url) denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy:Status code: 301

Tags: http, next.js, google-cloud-functions, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to deploy a firebase function and call the function from a nextjs app. The function works when it runs on firebase emulator, and when it is deployed I am able to call the function from postman. However, when deployed and I try to call using fetch I get an error. I have also tried to deploy the website to call from a different url but still get the same error.

Here is the calling function:

```
export async function getArticle(articleURL) {
  const response = await fetch(articleURL);
  const json = await response.json();
 
  return json.result;
}
```

Here is the firebase function that I am trying to call:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});


exports.getArticle = functions
  .runWith({
      timeoutSeconds: 120,
      memory: "1GB",
    })
    .https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
    cors(req, response, async() => {


    try {
      
      {code}


      response.status(200).json({ result: 'test' });
    }
    catch (e) {
      response.status(400).json({ result: "error", message: e.message });
    }finally {
      {code}
    }
       
     })
});
```

I have also tried adding headers such as:

```
response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"); 
     response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
```

but nothing seems to work. I have tried for hours but nothing works. The error I get is:

[Error] Cross-origin redirection to (url) denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 301

[Error] Fetch API cannot load (url) due to access control checks.

[Error] Failed to load resource: Cross-origin redirection to (url) denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 301

[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed

Lastly, I have also tried adding parameters to my fetch call such as :

```
fetch(URL, {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
})
```

Overall, nothing seems to work and don't know what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the firebase function but with the api call on nextjs. I was importing the function and making the call from a component. Instead I found the solution on this post: [NextJs CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue).

The solution that worked for me was by chispitaos. I changed my getArticle function to the api format and fetched the internal api which then fetched the firebase function. Here was my new function:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {

  
  try {


  const response = await fetch(`any url`);

  const json = await response.json();
  
    console.log(json);
  
  res.status(200).send(json);
   
 } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message)
  }

}
```

and here was how I called it :

```
 const newData = await fetch('/api/getArticle');
```

This fixed the issue for me.