# CORS preflight error only affecting Safari and Firefox

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, cors

I'm new to Next.js and server side rendering. I'm using the [Pexels API.](https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation?language=javascript#guidelines) Everything works as expected on Chrome, but on Firefox and Safari I'm encountering the following error.

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.pexels.com/v1//curated?per_page=10. (Reason: header ‘user-agent’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).`

I've looked at the Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers#connectexpress-middleware-support) as well as this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue) posts, but it's not clear to me how I'm suppose to create a rewrite so that I get around this error or run the middleware so I don't encounter this error?

Below is my next.config.js and api call. The domain that I want to whitelist is `api.pexels.com` Any help on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

```
// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  images: {
    domains: ["images.pexels.com", "www.pexels.com"],
  },
  transpilePackages: ['chic-ui'],
  compiler: {
    // Enables the styled-components SWC transform
    styledComponents: true
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig


// API call in pages/api
const key = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY;

const getCuratedPhotos = async (page?: number) => {
  console.log('pages', page)
  const client = createClient(key);
  try {
    if (!page) {
      return await client.photos.curated({ per_page: 10 });
    } else {
      return await client.photos.curated({ per_page: 10, page });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }
}
```