# Nextjs CORS issue and using same image for different environments

Tags: docker, next.js, cors, environment-variables, next.js13

This is in continuation to [NextJs CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue?newreg=deee8f5b15834ec682183923b25a3163)

If I use the following code, the base url differs based on environment and if I use process.env.API_BASE_URL in destination, then, API_BASE_URL variable needs to be passed at build time. Due to this, I am not able to promote same docker image to upper environments.

```
docker build --build-arg API_BASE_URL=<value> ...
```

Can someone help here?

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'https://api.example.com/:path*',
          },
        ]
      },
  };
```

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/:path*`,
          },
        ]
      },
  };
```

Comment: In ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) I suggest an approach using path-only URLs that doesn't depend on the deployed host name.  Can that be adapted to this setup?