# How to fetch data in a Next js 14 Client Component from external API

Tags: next.js, fetch, app-router, next.js14

I am using Next.js 14 App router. I know we can fetch data using server actions inside a Server Component. But, I require the page.tsx of a specific route to be a client component due to some reasons. Now, to fetch data inside a client component, we can use `useEffect()` and call the external api endpoint using `fetch()`. But, I am getting a CORS error in console even though the server to which I am making request is enabled to allow requests from all origins.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And getting the following error in Next.js error panel:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Also, I am able to fetch through the same endpoint, using the same `fetch()` through server actions.

There is one temporary solution to overcome this using rewrites in `next.config.js` as follows:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        {
          source: "/endpoint",
          destination:
            "https://exampleapi.com/endpoint",
        },
      ];
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Even though this overcomes CORS and solves the `Failed to fetch` runtime error. But, would have to create this for every endpoint. Is there any other way to fetch data in client component inside an useEffect using `fetch()` without updating `next.config.js`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJs CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue)

Comment: @ArnasDičkus No, I had already viewed that question, the problem itself is different. There the issue is faced in production and the question was posted 3 years ago when Next.js 14 wasn't released. My issue is in development and I want to know the ideal way to fetch data inside Client Components (Next 14 feature) without defining rewrites in next.config.js.