Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I've recently been working on an online invoice generator using the MERN Stack with TypeScript. I have included an option to generate a PDF using the Puppeteer library when a button is clicked. This feature works fine on my local device. I have deployed the backend of this project on Render and the frontend on Vercel. However, when I click on the button to generate the PDF on the deployed page, the following error appears:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://invoice-generator-1-yyv7.onrender.com/api/v1/generate-pdf' from origin 'https://invoice-ninja-aryan.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my cors:
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "*",
        credentials: true,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
    })
);

Below is the backend function implementing the generatePDF Function
app.post('/api/v1/generate-pdf', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const { user, products} = req.body;

    let totalRate = 0;
    const processedProducts = products.map(product => {
        const total = product.quantity * product.price;
        totalRate += total;
        return {
            ...product,
            total: total
        };
    });

    // Calculate total GST and grand total
    const totalGST = totalRate * 0.18; // Assuming GST rate is 18%
    const grandTotal = totalRate + totalGST;

    // Load HTML template
    const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, 'invoiceTemplate.html');
    const templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');

    // Compile template with Handlebars
    const template = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
    const html = template({
        userName: user.name,
        userEmail: user.email,
        products: processedProducts,
        totalRate: totalRate,
        totalGST: totalGST,
        grandTotal: grandTotal
    });
    // Launch Puppeteer and generate PDF
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        devtools: true,
        args: [
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
            '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
            '--disable-features=BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests'
        ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(html);
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ 
        path: 'mypdf.pdf',
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground: true,
    });
    await browser.close();

    // Send PDF as response
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': pdfBuffer.length
    });
    res.send(pdfBuffer);
});

Below is the Express Setup and the CORS Middleware:
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "*",
        credentials: true,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
    })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "*"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,CONNECT,TRACE"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Content-Type-Options, Accept, X-Requested-With, Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", true);
    //  Firefox caps this at 24 hours (86400 seconds). Chromium (starting in v76) caps at 2 hours (7200 seconds). The default value is 5 seconds.
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 7200);
  
    next();
  });

I attempted the methods suggested by others on Stack Overflow, but none of them worked for me. What can I try next?

Sounds like a pure Express/server issue unrelated to Puppeteer since the problem occurs between a button click and Express's middleware pipeline, but you're only showing the route handler that is never reached. Please show a [mcve] with the Express setup and the CORS middleware, as well as potentially the request code the front end is using, and any relevant server config necessary to repro the issue. Thanks.

Also, if you could link to the attempted solutions, that'd be great, so we can see what you've tried exactly, along with what happened when you tried each one.

@ggorlen Also, Sharing you my Github Repo: which contains both frontend and backend files. Backend files in 'serverL' folder and frontend in the 'src' folder
https://github.com/AryanBiswas198/Invoice-Generator

Thanks. Please [edit] the post to provide this information and delete these comments. If you're using the cors library, then you shouldn't need to add manual CORS headers. I'd use one or the other. Your code looks OK to me at a glance though.

I've tried both ways of either adding a manual CORS header or not into the code.
I got this solution of adding a manual CORS header from the below post.
https://community.render.com/t/no-access-control-allow-origin-header/12947
But trying all of the solutions gives me the same error on the browser console

Maybe Render is changing the response headers? I wouldn't be surprised if it's that.

I just remembered that you can put a rewrite in vercel.json to avoid cors issues

To debug, can you please add the statement res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get('Origin')) just above the statement res.send(pdfBuffer); ,then please see if the issue still persisting.

@WeDoTheBest4You it still gives me the same error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://invoice-generator-1-yyv7.onrender.com/api/v1/generate-pdf' from origin 'https://invoice-ninja-aryan.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

@pguardiario can you please share me the code that needs to be in the vercel.json file as my file doesn't contains the mentioned file

More bout rewrites: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue

@WTFitzAryan: in general people won't do private support here, as it is extremely inefficient. It could take them hours just to help one person. The idea here is to do all help in public, so that many people are helped. To facilitate this, you need to ensure that all relevant information is placed in the question itself.

Please try things one by one, step by step,  it will work.

Is the issue still persisting?

vercel.json should look something like
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/invoice/:path*",
      "destination": "https://invoice-generator-1-yyv7.onrender.com/api/v1/:path*"
    }
  ]
}

then you fetch from https://myapp.vercel.app/invoice/generate_pdf
