express cors not update origin
I deploy website that both use one domain but backend is sub domian something like api.domain.com when I try to call api from frontend it notice me a simple cors issue or error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/v1/path/path' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

First time, I think I forgot to set cors origin but when I check it set properly
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "https://www.example.com",
    credentials: true,
};
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.example.com');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true");

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

Then I use cors debugger:
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.vercel.app

It show my origin is my old domain I use vercel to host frontend then change to custom domain it seem origin not update when i set in cors option what I do wrong?
I'm trying to deploy website but cors origin not change properly

There may be url rewrites. Please check and comment the applicable content of vercel.json in the root directory of your app and test it. You may get more about url rewrites from these posts : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78577587/access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-all/78584137#78584137. https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/rewrites
